# Can't install Windows Azure Service Bus nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, nuget-package

I'm trying to add a nuget package to my project using the nuget package manager (right click and choosing "Manage Nugets").

I found the Windows Azure Service Bus and i'm clicking install. Then I get the following error:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager (≥ 2.0.2)'.
Successfully installed 'WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 2.2.1.1'.
Unexpected end of file while parsing Comment has occurred. Line 46, position 17.
Successfully uninstalled 'WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 2.2.1.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Unexpected end of file while parsing Comment has occurred. Line 46, position 17.
```

I tried it over and over and even tried restarting vs2012.

did anyone encounter this or know how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: did you try adding this package to a newly created project, may be something wrong with your project nuget setup or something? also you could try removing all the packages this sdk depends on and try fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a "Dependency Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager could not be resolved" error and had to separately install the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" nuget package (VS 2015).  This fixed the dependency problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tried installing WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package to a clean project and it did not repro for me.

I suspect that you have some special comments or sth like that in your web.config. Could you please share with us what you web.config look like? or feel free to file an issue on http://nuget.codeplex.com and describe the repro steps.