# asp.net 5 with azure service bus

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus

Has anyone used ASP.NET 5 with Azure Service Bus?  I tried adding the WindowsAzureServiceBus 3.0.2 nuget package to an ASP.NET5 application and Visual Studio cannot resolve Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager for DNX 4.5.1.

Error I get is

> Dependency Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager  could not be
>   resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems this is an old unresolved issue.

See related post: [Can't install Windows Azure Service Bus nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351904/cant-install-windows-azure-service-bus-nuget-package)

Similarly to the answer from the linked posted, I just manually added `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager` to the package.json. The dependency will be resolved and project will build. I tested sending a message to topic and things seem to work.

`...
"WindowsAzure.ServiceBus": "3.0.9",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.1.0"`

Comment: We'll take a look at this. I have a hunch why this fails.